Where is the Authorized Redirect URIs in Google API now?
I am using Google Drive API. I have set up my project, set the credentials on OAuth 2.0 Client IDs, filled in every item on OAuth Consent Screen. Neither from OAuth Consent Screen and the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs, I cannot find the authorized redirect URLs.
Where is it now? My project require me to set up the redirect URL.
I filled in all the item and still can't find the option.

Are they not located where the documentation explains? https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#oauth-client-id

what error are you getting exactly?

The Authorized Redirect URIs are set under each individual Client ID - see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingcred
